# Elements and Conjugacy Classes of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, direct-product

[image]Let

$G=(C_{p_1} : C_{3}) \times(C_{p_2} : C_{3})$

where $p_1,p_2\equiv{1}\pmod{3}$.

How many elements does the group $G$ have of each order?  Furthermore, what is the total number of conjugacy classes?

I assumed that G contains exactly p-1 elements of order p, 2(p-1) elements of order 3p and 2(3p+1) elements of order 3, for each p_{i}. But I could be wrong.

Similarly, can I ask the same question for $G= A_{4} \times(C_{p} : C_{3})$ where $p\equiv{1}\pmod{3}$.

I am trying to adapt a current proof where $G= C_{3} \times(C_{p} : C_{3})$ and $p\equiv{1}\pmod{3}$.  The proof is shown above and the authors claim that similar arguments can be used to prove the two cases I have presented above.

Comment: Please show your effort..... Then we will happy to help...:-)

Comment: I assumed that G contains exactly p-1 elements of order p, 2(p-1) elements of order 3p and 2(3p+1) elements of order 3, for each p_{i}.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Please add your thoughts; it's okay if you're incorrect, because then we have something to work with to help you move forward.  Could you copy your comment into you post?  Just click on the "Edit" tab below the statement of you comment.

Comment: Incidentally, you seem to be assuming that the semidirect products $C_{p_i}:C_3$ are nonabelian (i.e. the action is nontrivial), although you have not said that.

Comment: @DerekHolt that is true.  The semi-direct product is nonabelian.

Comment: Are you assuming that $p_1 \ne p_2$? If not, then $p_1=p_2$ would be a special case.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes in this instance, I am considering that both p are different or the same.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt.  So If $\Sigma$ is defined as the union of the conjugates of the cyclic subgroups generated by $x$, $y$ and $xy$ respectively. How does the order of the elements and the conjugacy classes that have been established help demonstrate the four Sigma sets in the above proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a direct product $G \times H$, the conjugacy classes are of the form $C \times D$, where $C$ and $D$ are conjugacy classes of $G$ and $H$, and the order of the elements in $C \times D$ is the least common multiple of the orders of elements in $C$ and in $D$. This makes it straightforward to answer your questions in direct products provided that we can answer them in the factors.

So lets apply that to the case when both $G$ and $H$ are nonabelian groups with structure $C_p:C_3$.

The factors have one element of order $1$, $p-1$ of order $p$ in $(p-1)/3$ classes, and two classes of elements of order $3$, both of size $p$.

So in $(C_{p_1}:C_3) \times (C_{p_2}:C_3)$ with $p_1 \ne p_2$, we have (if I have counted correctly):

one element of order $1$,

$p_1-1$ of order $p_1$ in $(p_1-1)/3$ classes,

$p_2-1$ of order $p_2$ in $(p_2-1)/3$ classes,

$2p_1 + 2p_2 + 4p_1p_2$ of order $3$ in $2 + 2 + 4 = 8$ classes,

$2p_2(p_1-1)$ of order $3p_1$ in $2(p_1-1)/3$ classes,

$2p_1(p_2-1)$ of order $3p_2$ in $2(p_2-1)/3$ classes, and

$(p_1-1)(p_2-1)$ of order $p_1p_2$ in $(p_1-1)(p_2-1)/9$ classes.

The only significant difference when $p_1=p_2$ is that the elements in the final class have order $p_1$.